# Resize/modify Arrows in Gimp

Tags: gimp, resize

I have added the arrow.scm script to Gimp and can create arrows to my liking.

I want to use arrows on my documentation which point to buttons, switches etc. so sometimes need to adjust the arrows at a later date when I modify the (label) text.
I have a few question which I have not been able to solve, even after searching for many hours.

My first question relates to creating the arrow.

1. Is there an easy way to create the arrow perfectly horizontal (or vertical)?

The following questions refer to modifying the arrow **after** it has already been created using the Tools->Arrow... (i.e. I double-click the specific Arrow Layer, but then what?)

1. How can I resize the arrow (make it shorter or longer without making it fatter or thinner)?
2. How can I change the arrow color?
3. How can I make the arrow a little fatter or thinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use guides and snap to guides to get perfectly horizontal or vertical paths.

You can't really modify the arrow after it has been created.  The script renders a raster image, and so it's not editable as an arrow.  If it's on its own layer however, you can delete the layer, and then create a new arrow on a new layer.

If the arrow is on its own transparent layer, changing the colour is easy enough. Just enable the Alpha Lock on the layer and do *Edit > Fill with FG/BG Colour*

If you find yourself making lots of arrows that you need to edit afterwards, perhaps consider using Inkscape instead. It's is an open source vector image editor (and free) and allows you to change the stroke colour, direction, thickness and arrow heads after you've made them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the precise information and instructions.
Using a grid works perfectly as does changing the color of the arrow.
I doubt I would have figured those out on my own.
I really appreciate your help.